# Write several strings to one xml file vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, string

I am writing a string to a xml document.

I now have several different strings and I want to write all of them to one xml file. Is there any way of doing this instead of having numerous single xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing strings out, use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to construct the XML structure and [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338419.aspx) to a file.

This will keep you from making mistakes in the format of the XML file itself, as XML is not simple text, but a structured file format.

Comment: Im fairly new to vb.net and i needed to get the contents of my dictionary to xml format. I thought the easiest way to do this was to use a string builder that would write the contents in a basic xml output.

Comment: @ASmith - Superficially, perhaps. But by doing so you can end up with invalid XML easily and find it difficult to find _where_ the error is. A strongly typed way safeguards you from such errors.

Comment: @ASmith - It doesn't matter whether you are newbie or not. You must have to use DOM, XDocument or SAX parsert to write/read XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file.AppendText` to add to a file.

Comment: Which will result in an invalid XML file.

Comment: @Oded, yes, but as far as I can see the question did not state that the file should be valid xml.

Comment: It is implied. If you write to a file, you expect to read from it. And if it is XML, why make it invalid for reading?

Comment: Is it? I must say the question was quite specific, he wanted to write to one file for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.IO.File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx#Y0) instead of System.IO.File.WriteAllText

Comment: Which will result in an invalid XML file.